# How Clojure's let is a special form?

Tags: clojure

As I understood special forms in Clojure are building blocks that will be used to construct the rest of the language features. WRT let, as I see let is defined as a macro [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4447). How is it a special form then?

Comment: Note that it's the same with `loop`, `if`, and `fn`. None are actually special forms themselves. They're all wrapper macros that defer to `*` variants. It would be nice if the docs were a little clearer about that; although I suppose that would only complicate matters to new Clojurists.

Comment: Not `if`. `if` is actually special.

Comment: @amalloy Oops, you're right. Ya, I guess `if` wouldn't really require any preprocessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking `let` is just a front-end to `let*`, which is a special form. `let` adds parameter checks and destructuring, but for all other purposes (from a programmer's point of view) it is a special form.